# Exception in camera_calibration with Bumblebee

Tags: ros, bumblebee

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the camera_calibration package to calibrate (both cameras of) the bumblebee 2 camera.

The images are being published correctly with topic names `/camera/0/intensity` and `/camera/1/intensity`.
I can view the images in the viewer and I can see the values with `rostopic echo`.

When I run this command, nothing seems to happen:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/camera/0/intensity camera:=/camera/0 --no-service-check
```

I also tried to calibrate just one camera:

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/camera/0/intensity camera:=/camera/0 --no-service-check
```

But in the case of one camera I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner self.run()
    File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/camera_calibration/cameracalibrator.py", line 93, in run self.function(m)
    File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/camera_calibration/cameracalibrator.py", line 175, in handle_monocular drawable = self.c.handle_msg(msg)
    File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 691, in handle_msg gray = self.mkgray(msg)
    File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 255, in mkgray return self.br.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, "mono8")
    File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cv_bridge/core.py", line 121, in imgmsg_to_cv2 dtype=dtype, buffer=img_msg.data)
    TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with ROS Indigo and the calibration does work with other cameras. Does anyone have a clue how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193732/exception-in-camera_calibration-with-bumblebee/) by [Ronald](https://answers.ros.org/users/20340/ronald/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-09-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2014-09-29**:
Did you install all of the dependencies for camera calibration? Try rosdep install camera_calibration

**Comment by [Ronald](https://answers.ros.org/users/20340/ronald/) on 2014-09-30**:
All dependencies were installed with rosdep install camera_calibration, but unfortunately that did not solve it. I got exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not really a direct answer, but:

> [..]
> TypeError: buffer is too small for requested array

These kind of errors are typically caused by the input byte array (in this case: `img_msg.data`) not having the expected layout, and thus not the required number of bytes to successfully convert into the desired `dtype`. That or the input array is really too small, for instance because of an incorrect assumption on image size / depth. See the [Converting between ROS images and OpenCV images](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) tutorial for some info on image encodings.

I'm not too familiar with `imgmsg_to_cv2(..)`, but could it be that the images coming from your camera are not actually in the format that `cv_bridge` expects?

---

The [Bumblebee Reverse engineering Calibration](http://answers.ros.org/question/60098/bumblebee-reverse-engineering-calibration/) question (and in particular [the answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/60098/bumblebee-reverse-engineering-calibration/?answer=60100#post-id-60100) by William) also could be interesting.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ronald](https://answers.ros.org/users/20340/ronald/) on 2014-09-30**:
There are no problems with camera_calibration if I use the package pointgrey_camera_driver to publish the Bumblebee2 images. I think that you are right that the published topic I was using did not have the layout that was expected by camera_calibration.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-09-30**:
Which package were you using originally? Might be an idea to contact the maintainer and try to figure out what went wrong. Also, `rostopic echo` should show you the actual encoding of the `/camera/0/intensity` topic.

**Comment by [Ronald](https://answers.ros.org/users/20340/ronald/) on 2014-09-30**:
The encoding is indeed different. The pointgrey_camera_package is publishing /camera/left/image_raw with bayer_grbg8 encoding. I was publishing and using /camera/0/intensity with bgr8 encoding before.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-09-30**:
This was custom code that interfaced with the camera(s)? No package maintainer to contact then.

**Comment by [Ronald](https://answers.ros.org/users/20340/ronald/) on 2014-09-30**:
I was indeed using custom code.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-09-30**:
Shame on you then :). Perhaps add your solution as an answer and use it to mark the question as answered.